# Am I using filter right? I don't know why this solution works

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm going through FCC basic algorithms right now, and while I passed the exercise, I'm not fully understanding why it works, as when I change things to how I think they should be it doesn't work, but when I change things so they look wrong to me it still works.

For instance, I change `true` to `false`, and it still works, or I just type true, and it still works, or I just say `return value`, and it works.  Does filter automatically remove *falsy* values?

Here is my code. My original code that didn't work said `if (value === true)`.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  let x = arr.filter(value => {
    if (value !== true)
      return value;
  })
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}   

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Remove all *falsy* values from an array.

*Falsy* values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the answers, they were all super helpful in clearing up my confusion.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  let x = arr.filter(ages => {
    return ages;
  })
  return(x);
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

This is the solution I ended up re-writing, and now understand why I did what I did.

Comment: "*when I change things to how i think they should be, it doesn't work*" - what does that look like?

Comment: Be aware that you don't always `return ` a value, and if you don't, then the return value is `undefined` which is also falsy. You could just do `.filter(Boolean)` to kick out all falsy values.

Comment: if  (value === true)

Comment: so i could just say arr.filter(Boolean), and that's it?

Comment: If indeed your purpose is to keep only truthy values, then `Boolean` is the callback function you need. But `.filter(x => x)` would work just as well. But your question is not entirely clear on what you *want*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback,

```
if (value !== true)
  return value;
```

is equivalent to just

```
return value;
```

in your case because none of the elements in your array are `true`, so `value !== true` always holds.

If you change it to

```
if (value !== false)
    return value;
```

it still executes `return value;` for most array elements. The only exception is `false`, for which your function returns `undefined` (because no explicit `return` statement is executed). `undefined` is falsy, so it is treated the same as `return false` by `filter` (because `filter` only cares whether the callback returned a true or falsy value). So in the end not returning a value if the element is `false` is the same as `return value`.

On the other hand, if you change it to

```
if (value === true)
    return value;
```

then your callback would return `true` if the current element is `true` and return `undefined` for any other value. The net effect is removing all elements that are not `true` (which in your case is all elements because your input array does not contain `true`).

If you want to remove falsy values, you can simply say

```
arr.filter(value => { return value; })
// or:
arr.filter(value => value)
```

because you're using the value itself as the condition: Anything that looks falsy is removed by `filter`; anything that looks true is kept.

If you find this confusing, perhaps looking at this custom (and simplified) `filter` implementation clears things up:

```js
function my_filter(arr, fn) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (fn(arr[i])) {
            results.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

// Usage would be something like:

console.log(my_filter([7, "ate", "", false, 9], value => value));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, and explanation, it greatly helped!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` iterates over your array. In each element iteration the callback is called.

If you return a "truthy" value in the callback that element is kept in the resulting Array, otherwise it's not.

Your confusion stems from the fact that you think you need to return the `value` argument in some way. **You don't**.

Look at this example:

```js
var animals = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat']

var cats = animals.filter(value => {
  if (value === 'cat') {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
})

console.log(cats)
```

Of course the above can be simplified to this:

```js
var animals = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat']

var cats = animals.filter(value => {
  return value === 'cat'
})

console.log(cats)
```

That's just it.

Comment: !== true = false tho, or am i missing something.  why would it return the true values still, and filter the falsy ones.

Comment: Forget about the passed `value` as the callback argument. You have that available as a helper to decide if you want to return `true` or `false`. You might as well just put only `return true` in your callback in which case all the items will be kept. `filter` only cares if you return `true` or `false`, it doesn't require you return the `value` argument in any way. I'll add an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to return an array that only retains the truthy values, then do this:

```
.filter(Boolean)
```

In your callback to `filter` you don't always return a value, and if you don't, that means the corresponding value will not be retained. Furthermore, with operators like `!==` and `===` you are doing a *strict*  comparison. So `value === true` will *only* match `true`, not *any* other truthy value. Similarly, `value !== true` will still match some truthy values (that are not `true`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I did end up remembering from past lessons to use == to compare truthy/falsy, over ===.